# Anime where character's hand transforms?

Tags: mardock-scramble

I discovered this animated image: http://gfycat.com/SoftDesertedAyeaye

[image]

What anime is this from?

In the animation, the character runs from 2 guys, but gets cornered.  At this time, the hand appears to act on it's own, transforming into tools to subdue the pursuers.

I've tried Google's search by image tool, but no help.  I'm also not sure what "Soft Deserted Ayeaye" would mean, but [searching it brings up some creepy animal pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=Soft+Deserted+Aye+aye).

Comment: The gfycat Google search result mentions Mardock, presumably as in Mardock Scramble. That may be it, or a comment or something

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I think you might be correct.  [This image](http://www.cartoonbrew.com/wp-content/uploads/mardock.jpg) has a similar looking character.

Comment: FYI, the gfycat URLs like "SoftDesertedAyeaye" are randomly generated sequences of words and have nothing to do with the image itself.

Comment: I don't understand how people have so much trouble with this stuff.  Reverse image search of the image **you** provided immediately returns several mentions of a movie Mardock Scramble.  Following up a google of **Mardock Scramble** leads to info about the anime, and pictures of the character...

Comment: @Doc I tried that feature and even mentioned that in my question.  I make no claim to understand how it works, but when I asked this question I did not get any helpful results using reverse image search.

Comment: [Reverse Image Search](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html).  If you're using chrome, right click the image above and select "Search google for this image".  If you do so, the first several results will be in foreign languages, but will mention "Mardock Scramble" "Movie" "2011".  One of them names the full title: "Mardock Scramble The First Compression".  From there, just refine your search with that name.

Comment: Also, as a point, from the .gif you linked, if you hover your mouse over the gif, you'll see below it "Reddit comments: /r/animegifs".  Click the link and the thread it links to is a recommendation to watch the anime >_>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As our discussion in the comments suggest, the anime you are looking for is Mardock Scramble

[image]

> The story is about a girl named Rune Ballot who was taken in by a man named Shell who later tried to kill her and left her for dead. She is saved and turned into a cyborg. It is up to her to stop Shell and his evil gang.

[Ref. Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mardock_Scramble)

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles here following the title, the anime where the character's hand transforms into a girl is called Midori no Hibi.